# How to access Data Saver/Network settings using ADB commands?

Tags: android, adb, android-tv

trying to open Data Saver menu using ADB Commands in Android TV 9, Philips 2020. Philips covered stock Network menu using their own, so there is no way to enable/disable Data Saver as it was installed.

https://beebom.com/enable-data-saver-mode-android-tv/

https://source.android.com/devices/tech/connect/data-saver

Any help witch command I can try to display this menu or simply enable/disable Data Saver feature will be appreciated. I connected using ADB my TV with terminal in my PC already.

Commands like that works, no surprise:

```
adb shell am start -a android.settings.system
```

But when I tried to use more complex ones I get errors, nothing opens on the TV. I based on this doc - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings

```
adb shell am start -a android.settings.SETTINGS.system

Starting: Intent { act=android.settings.SETTINGS.system } Error: Activity not started, unable to resolve Intent { act=android.settings.SETTINGS.system flg=0x10000000 }
```

If there is a command to do so, I can map it later using Button Mapper, so it will be more user friendly in daily use.

Comment: I don't know what settings activities are available on an AndroidTV. But you can find it out yourself: Download the APK file of the settings app and check it's `AndroidManifest.xml` (via apktool or Jadx, ..). All activities you can open have to be declared in this file.

Comment: Thats sounds like a good idea. Do you mean dump somehow app from my TV? I do not see any Android 9 TV settings apk when I googled. Or are somewhere official Android resources to get that that app?

Comment: Yes I was talking about extracting the APK file from the AndroidTV device. This should be possible via ADB or some File-Manager apps can extract APK files.

Comment: Thanks, I was able to to dump settings.apk. Here is full AndroidManifest.xml - https://pastebin.com/6P8KdDfz

I tried to enter some promissing parts, but no sucess yet. Any recommendations would be welcome.

Comment: C:\Users\Szymon\Desktop\Tiny ADB & Fastboot v1.4.0 Portable>adb shell am start -a org.droidtv.settings.setupmenu.WirelessAndNetworkSettingsActivity
Starting: Intent { act=org.droidtv.settings.setupmenu.WirelessAndNetworkSettingsActivity }
Error: Activity not started, unable to resolve Intent { act=org.droidtv.settings.setupmenu.WirelessAndNetworkSettingsActivity 

C:\Users\Szymon\Desktop\Tiny ADB & Fastboot v1.4.0 Portable>adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN
Starting: Intent { ac
Warning: Activity not started, intent has been delivered to currently running top-most instance.